# Curved top border with mat-toolbar

Tags: angular-material

I am using mat-toolbar and I would like to create bottom navigation. Similar to this:
[image]

I am not able to get a curve at top border

My result:
[image]

Here is my code:

HTML

```xml
<div class="footer">   
    <mat-toolbar class="toolbarNav">
        <mat-icon class="material-icons color_blue" >home</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon class="material-icons color_blue">question_answer</mat-icon>
       <div class="create"> <button type="button" class="btn btn_create"
            (click)="openDialog()"><img  src="../../../assets/icons/Group 2090.svg"></button></div>
        <mat-icon class="material-icons color_blue" >notifications</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon class="material-icons color_blue" >person</mat-icon>
    </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code here as well?

Comment: Yes sure @TomTom

Answer (score 0):

I suppose one good solution is using background svg's in your proposed forms, have you tried it out? There is one example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8uxnb4?file=src/app/toolbar-overview-example.css showing to add an image as background, if you utilize SVG, it will allow you all shapes you like, if you need an simple svg for test purpose let me know and I create you one for test purpose.